# Use of SqlBulkInsert in production applications

Tags: c#, sql, database, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

We are currently developing an application that generates upwards of 5-10,000 rows of data in a particular table for each user session. Currently we are using sql text commands to insert each row of data at a time so a save operation could take up to a minute. We are playing around with the use of SqlBulkInserts and have seen the time go down to less than 500ms. Does anyone have any objection with the use of SqlBulkInserts in a production application where many users will be using the system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have never ran into an issue with SqlBulkCopy with the tableLock option set and another user being blocked due to it. The TableLock option increases the efficiency of the insert from what many people have talked about and just plain using it have shown me.

My typical method:

```
public void Bulk(String connectionString, DataTable data, String destinationTable)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
            new SqlBulkCopy
            (
            connection,
            SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock |
            SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers |
            SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction,
            null
            ))
        {
            bulkCopy.BatchSize = data.Rows.Count;
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = String.Format("[{0}]", destinationTable);
            connection.Open();
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Before implementing using SqlBulkInsert, try creating your `INSERT` query dynamically to look like this:

```
insert into MyTable (Column1, Column2)
select 123, 'abc'
union all
select 124, 'def'
union all
select 125, 'yyy'
union all
select 126, 'zzz'
```

This will be only one database call, which should run much more quickly. For the SQL string concatenation, make sure you use the `StringBuilder` class.

Comment: I did entertain this idea but my problem with this approach is I need the identity value that was created for the primary key back on the server as we are building a hierarchy tree since this is a self referencing table.

Comment: So what? This totlaly rules out the use of SqlBulkCopy, too - how you do bulk inserts if you need the server generated ID back? The answer is valid, your commend contradicts your own statement.

Comment: Your right and I am an idiot. What we are doing in the SqlBulkCopy implementation was retrieving the list of data that we just inserted at each level of the tree to retrieve the list of id's that were generated. I didn't even think about doing the same thing with using the statement you provided above.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the right way to go, if your application really needs to produce that many records per session.

Comment: Because of the way our database is structured, we have 12 tables that we are storing data to in a single transaction, because of this we were getting deadlocks errors while using SqlBulkCopy. By setting the SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock the deadlocks went away. Is there any disadvantage of locking the table to do the bulk inserts? Will it hurt other users trying to run a transaction at the same time?

Comment: You mean except you ahve a TAbLE LOCK? next you come and whine about having table locks ;) Deadlocks are a different thing and a sign of your programming being badly done - fix the problems as they occur, dont put bad code over bad code to avod symptoms.

Comment: I would completely agree with you if I didn't have a product manager yelling down my back to not change a single thing about the database schema except for maybe some indexes and make everything perform better. I have been completely flustered by the entire situation.